# Cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector2' to 'UnityEngine.Transform' when instantiating a 2D object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to clone gameobjects however I keep getting the following error:

> BoxDuplication.cs(18,60): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.Vector2' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BoxDuplication : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject boxOriginal;

    void Start()
    {
        CreateBox(3);
    }

    void CreateBox(int boxNum)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < boxNum; i ++)
        {
            GameObject boxClone = Instantiate(boxOriginal, new Vector2(boxOriginal.transform.position.x, i));
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried putting instantiate standalone with set co-ordinates:

```
GameObject boxClone = Instantiate(boxOriginal, new Vector2(1, 1));
```

but this doesn't work either so there's something wrong with my method

I've tried to figure out what I'm doing wrong by looking through videos and other stack-overflow posts but due to not really knowing much c# I'm at a loss. There are a few similar posts like this but I don't think they answer my problem. If they do, then I guess I don't understand the concept.

Thanks, Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: This error is easily fixed by reading the intellisense suggestions in [Visual Studio](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/set-your-default-script-editor-ide#62a054a2edbc2a0ff716bf05) (Unity's preferred code editor). You should try to fix your problems on your own then Google the issue before posting on StackOverflow.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.html) yet? They’re actually REALLY good to help you work out any issues you might be having. Sometimes there’s a phrase or two that are hidden away but explain so much. Super helpful and absolutely worth checking out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Unity Docs, the Instantiate Decelerations are:

1. `public static Object Instantiate(Object original);`
2. `public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent);`
3. `public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent, bool instantiateInWorldSpace);`
4. `public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);`
5. `public static Object Instantiate(Object original, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Transform parent);`

So in your case, the Instantiate method expects a parent `Transform`. You will have to include the rotation and parent as well.

So your line becomes:

```
GameObject boxClone = Instantiate(boxOriginal, new Vector2(1, 1), Quaternion.identity, transform);
```

**EDIT:**

The `transform` is used as a parent. It can be omitted as needed. It is always a good idea to spawn objects as a child. To make a hierarchy clean.

Comment: [Link to Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

Comment: PickledPie never mentioned wanting to add the boxClone as a child of the script object

Comment: It can be omitted as needed. It is always a good idea to spawn objects as a child. To make a hierarchy clean.

Comment: I agree but it was not asked for. PickledPie seems to lack a basic understanding of Unity functions and might not know about [Unity Learn](https://learn.unity.com/) which can be very helpful. Also, adding extra variables to your answer without explanations will just lead to confusion. The only necessary addition was the rotation.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your advice. Will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score -1):

Your issue is that you are not setting the rotation of the new GameObject.
If you want to use `Instantiate(boxOriginal, transform)` that would set it as a child of the object that your script is attached to. That would work, you would just need to add `boxClone.transform.position += Vector3(1,1);` to move it to the desired position. *Note* `boxClone.transform.localPosition` may be what you want instead.

If you use `GameObject boxClone = Instantiate(boxOriginal, new Vector2(1, 1), Quaternion.identity);` then you should have no issues.